# Applying CSS styles to an element by XPath

Tags: css, xpath

I am trying to apply a style (`display:none`) to an element without an `ID` or `class`...
The only way I can consistently reach this element is through XPath.

I have copied the XPath from chrome developer tools, which is:

```
*[@id="ABCDEF_container"]/div[3]/a
```

However I am stuck...
How do I write this in my CSS file?

Comment: Using the developer tool, instead of extracting the xpath, you can choose to export  the `selector` instead. (Right Click DOM element > Copy > Copy selector)

Comment: Is there no way you can add a selector?

Comment: Ahh! Thanks @Jonathan. You can copy the selector

Answer (score 0):

Try to access it using child selectorsb

Answer (score 0):

```css
*[id="ABCDEF_container"] > div:nth-child(3) > a {
  background: royalblue;
}
```